# Refactoring nested loop to a lambda expression

Tags: java

I'm trying to refactor the following code to a lambda function:

```
private Optional<String> fetchByNumList(ObjectId objectId) {

    List<Reference> numList = objectId.getNumList();

    if (!numList.isEmpty()) {

        for (Reference numRef : numList) {
            Optional<String> otherNum = findOtherNum(numRef);
            if (otherNum.isPresent()) {
                return otherNum;
            }

        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}

private Optional<String> findOtherNum(Reference numRef) {

    List<String> numRefList = numRef.getNumRefList();

    if (!numRefList.isEmpty()) {

        for (String num : numRefList) {
            Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(num);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                return Optional.of(matcher.group(3));
            }
        }

    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

This is what i have so far:

```
private Optional<String> fetchByNumListLambda(ObjectId objectId) {

    return objectId.getNumList().stream()
            .map(numRef -> { numRef.getNumRefList().stream()
                    .map(num -> {
                        Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(num);
                        if (!matcher.matches()) {
                            return Optional.of(matcher.group(3));
                        }
                        return Optional.<String>empty();
                    });
                return Optional.<String>empty(); //I believe this is the one, overriding the value to Optional.empty.
            })
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(Optional.empty());
}
```

However, when I run, it returns Optional.empty. I'm sure it could be clean up, I'm still trying to get the hang of lambdas. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how robust it is to have a return inside a return

Comment: @NomadMaker this is absolutely fine, the return in the lambda is bound to just that, it will not leap multiple contexts like an old `goto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Optional<String> fetchByNumList(ObjectId objectId) {
    return objectId.getNumList().stream()
            .map(n -> n.getNumRefList().stream()
                    .map(REGEX_PATTERN::matcher)
                    // pre Java 11 .filter(m -> !m.matches())
                    .filter(Predicate.not(Matcher::matches))
                    .findAny()
                    .map(p -> Optional.of(p.group(3)))
                    .orElse(Optional.empty()))
            .findAny()
            .orElse(Optional.empty());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works great and is way more cleaner! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your lambda function is not equal to your nested loop. In your nested loop you check whether "matcher.matches()", if outcome is true you return Optional.of(matcher.group(3)).

However the statement in your lambda function does the opposite, you check for "!matcher.matches()", and then return Optional.of(matcher.group(3)).

I think it returns Optional.empty because your code in the lambda should be:

```
if (matcher.matches()) {
   return Optional.of(matcher.group(3));
}
```

Instead of:

```
if (!matcher.matches()) {
   return Optional.of(matcher.group(3));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response, I made the tweak you mentioned, however the results seems to be the same, I'm still getting Optional.empty back. I believe the second return Optional.<String>empty();, is replacing/overriding the match result. Is there anyway I can pass the return value from the inner most lambda outward?

Comment: Lambda expressions don't support getting the return value inside the function itself. In that case you would need to rewrite your function. You can check Robert's answer, there is only 1 return inside his lambda.

You can write lambda's for complex functions like this, however I find normal functions easier to read and I don't believe it is considered bad practice.